# c# propertygrid, how to refresh the specific property?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox, refresh, propertygrid

i have question c# propertygrid about refresh item of combobox.

now combobox item is "a","b", then pressed the btn1, i want to visible "1","2","3" in combobox.

first view my source.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private MyObject instance;
    public string[] str = new string[] { "a", "b" };

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        instance = new MyObject(this);
        this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = instance;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        str = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.propertyGrid1.Refresh();
    }
}

public class MyObject
{

    public Window1 refF;

    public MyObject(Window1 f)
    {
        this.refF = f;
    }

    private string objectName;

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ObjectNameConverter))]
    public string ObjectName
    {
        get {
            return objectName;
        }

        set {
            objectName = value;
        }

    }
}

public class ObjectNameConverter : StringConverter
{
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        MyObject refMyObject = context.Instance as MyObject;

        return new StandardValuesCollection(refMyObject.refF.str);
    }
}
```

when btn1 pressed, don't change item.

but i pressed btn2, changed item to my wants.

how can i change to combobox list item automatically not using refresh?

please help me.

thanks.

Comment: Items are changed, but the combo needs to be reopened to see them (when clicking on btn1, the combo is dismissed). What do you want to be "refreshed" exactly?

Comment: let me know reopen the combobox. it is my question. not using refresh.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, please explain more

Comment: when bt1 is pressed, item of combobox(property:ObjectName) are chagned. but it need to refresh. i want how to refresh the specific property(only one property). casof i have many property in propertygrid.